# Recommended way to generate a presigned url to S3 Bucket in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ruby

I am trying to generate a pre-signed url on my Rails server to send to the browser, so that the browser can upload to S3.

It seems like `aws-sdk-s3` is the gem to use going forward. But unfortunately, I haven't come across documentation for the gem that would provide clarity. There seem to be a few different ways of doing so, and would appreciate any guidance on the difference in the following methods -

1. Using `Aws::S3::Presigner.new` (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/s3/presigner.rb) but it doesn't seem to take in an object parameter or auth credentials.
2. Using `Aws::S3::Resource.new`, but it seems like `aws-sdk-resources` is not going to be maintained. (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/upgrading-from-version-2-to-version-3-of-the-aws-sdk-for-ruby-2/)
3. Using `Aws::S3::Object.new` and then calling the `put` method on that object.
4. Using `AWS::SigV4` directly.

I am wondering how they differ, and the implications of choosing one over the other? Any recommendations are much appreciated, especially with `aws-sdk-s3`.

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with using the sdk to do the image upload for you?

Comment: I am trying avoid the extra hop or complexity of first uploading the files to my server.

Comment: Here's the function for it in the Ruby sdk. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html

Comment: right, but then I see other docs using `Resource.new` and am not sure the implications of different ways to do this. Here is an example: https://www.ajostrow.me/articles/s3-client-uploads

Comment: From the example you gave it just creating a new S3 client then uses a function to generate the url. Or you can call the Ruby class for the presigned url function and feed it a bucket name.

Comment: The AWS sdk's serach four places for credentials if you don't specific them. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html#Configuration

Answer (score 20):

So, thanks to the tips by @strognjz above, here is what worked for me using `aws-sdk-s3'.

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

#credentials below for the IAM user I am using
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region:               'us-west-2', #or any other region
  access_key_id:        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secret_access_key:    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new(client: s3)
url = signer.presigned_url(
  :put_object,
  bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
  key: "${filename}-#{SecureRandom.uuid}"
)
```

Comment: Getting error <Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>X-Amz-Algorithm only supports "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"</Message>
<RequestId>3C113212318E91FE</RequestId>
<HostId>
NMKudxNE0q91Xm/rgqlNTwl7ZXGVvaOT0EeCZRmTkULuyh2BLiIDLXOwJ6soRm9TtqieCEh9ENc=
</HostId>
</Error>

Answer (score 17):

This will work using the aws-sdk-s3 gem

```
aws_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region:               'us-west-2', #or any other region
  access_key_id:        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secret_access_key:    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)


s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: aws_client)
bucket = s3.bucket('bucket-name')
obj = bucket.object("${filename}-#{SecureRandom.uuid}")

url = obj.presigned_url(:put)
```

## additional http verbs:

```
obj.presigned_url(:put)                              
obj.presigned_url(:head)                    
obj.presigned_url(:delete)
```

Comment: :get is also a method. For the full list, here's the documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#presigned_url-instance_method