# Adding embed video from S3 with Activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, activeadmin

I'm new with activeadmin and have searched everywhere for a solution to my problem.  I'm building a subscription based site and paying customers will have access to the videos.  I'm using Activeadmin but am having trouble with coding S3 within my app so I can use it in my Activeadmin dashboard.  I was able to find coding for Wistia and it works perfectly - but haven't found anything with Amazon S3.  Here is my apps->views->tasks->show.html.erb

[show.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6O2U.png)

Any help would be awesome!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Is your question about having the videos displayed in ActiveAdmin from S3, or is your question that you want videos uploaded to go to S3?

Comment: Videos displayed in ActiveAdmin from S3.  Is there any way I can embed them (eg in the body) within ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it but I believe you can use the [HTML5 video tag](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html) and an [S3 signed URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741473/recommended-way-to-generate-a-presigned-url-to-s3-bucket-in-ruby). I'm guessing it would look something like:

```
aws_resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(credentials: credentials)
presigner = Aws::S3::Presigner.new(client: aws_resource.client)
video(width: 320, height: 240) do
  source(src: presigner.presigned_url(:get_object, bucket: bucket_name, key: file.key))
end
```

There are also third party solutions you might look at like [Flowplayer](http://demos.flowplayer.com/scripting/signed-ondemand.html) and [Foliovision](https://foliovision.com/player/video-hosting/secure-amazon-s3-guide)