# How to authorize access to images uploaded to S3 by users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, authorization, carrierwave, fog

Imagine the app with the ability to upload files by users. Only the author (the person who uploaded this file) and the author's friends should be able to see this uploaded file.

I am using ["carrierwave" gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to handle uploading files. It gives me the ability to get a file URL.

```rb
# models/user.rb
class User
  mount_uploader :secret_file, SecretFileUploader
end

# uploaders/secret_file_uploader.rb
class SecretFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
    
  def extension_white_list
    %w[txt]
  end
       
  def store_dir
    "secret_files"
  end
end
    
    
u = User.last.secret_file.url # => "https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/secret_files/secret_file_name.txt"
```

If someone stoles this S3 URL, then they can access this file at any time.

How to handle this situation? How to authorize only the author and the author's friends to open this file?

Comment: You should never allow direct public access to an S3 bucket. It should be allowed through an IAM role.  In other words only your app should have access to the bucket, and then you can use your app's knowledge of the users to decide which files can be accessed.

Comment: @dbugger I know that I should keep my S3 bucket private. The question is how exactly to handle the authorization part. I see two ways to handle it.
1. Implementing the controller that downloads a file from S3 and sends it to a user if they are authorized to access it. I see a cons here - it probably will decrease the performance of an application a lot.
2. Using signed_url feature of S3. The cons here - there is still a possibility to steal/guess a URL and download a file.

Comment: Either approach works -- unless you have huge files 1. will be fine. If you have large files -- 2 is probably a better approach. Guessing a pre-signed url is not gonna happen without a ridiculous amount of computing power and time.

Comment: @dbugger
So for the second option basically It should be enough to make a bucket private and replace all URLs with pre-signed ones?

Comment: Make it private and when an authorized user requests a file -- generate a pre-signed url and provide to the user. No need to create them ahead of time.

Comment: @dbugger thanks, that is actually what I mean) sorry for the miss explanation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended way to generate a presigned url to S3 Bucket in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741473/recommended-way-to-generate-a-presigned-url-to-s3-bucket-in-ruby)

Comment: I believe when you generate URLs it's also possible to include an expiry. If you use a relatively short one, this should also help mitigate the risk of stolen or guessed URLs. As mentioned, guessing seems pretty unlikely, but stealing or revealing them could be a concern in some use cases.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure uploaded content is only visible to the users and its associated friends, you need to make sure few things -

1. You **need to associate every uploaded content**, like - user.images showing only user images.
2. You have to **create presigned url**s - they are like single use urls which can be used only once and have an expiration to avoid misuse.

```
##in user.rb
has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy

##in image.rb
belongs_to :user
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validates_presence_of :image
  ##to validate uploads - https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-uploads-with-Active-Record
  validates_integrity_of :image
  validates_processing_of :image

image_uploader.rb
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  #Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  #This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  #this way you ensure the files are uploaded to each users folders
  def store_dir
      "inputs/images/#{model.user_id}/#{model.id}"
  end

 ##in carrierwave.rb, you configure presigned urls using fog gem.
 CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    :aws_secret_access_key  => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    :region                 => "any valid aws region"
  }
  
  #this is where you configure presigned urls
  config.fog_directory  = "dev-bucket"
  config.fog_attributes = {
    expires: 10.minutes.from_now.httpdate,
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=315576000',
    server_side_encryption: 'aws:kms'
  }
  #default is 60 seconds
  config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 60
end
```

once done, you can use something in your views like -
@user.images to view all images of a user. you can extend this with any logic to show all list of images to the users friends.

Try it out and let me know if it helps.

To know more about how to avoid unwanted access to your files in AWS S3, [CHECK THIS LINK](https://pawelurbanek.com/rails-secure-s3-uploads)